# help converting this table to divs and css

Tags: html, css

This is driving me insane. how can i achieve the same effect like the table below but with divs and css.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>label1</label></td>
        <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>label2</label></td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT

If foo or bar are long paragraphs they should not flow under the label column

Comment: Semantically speaking, what are you using the LABELs for?  Is it a form?

Comment: @Blender Im starting to wonder the same thing grr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label> Label1 </label>
        Foo
    </li>
    <li>
        <label> Label2 </label>
        Bar
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/RFhur/1/

---

**Styled live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/RFhur/2/

---

Comment: when foo is a long paragraph i dont want it to flow into the label column

Answer (score 1):

Fixed width, floated labels are one way:

```
<p>
    <label style="width: 100px; float: left;">Label 1</label> Foo
</p>

<p>
    <label style="width: 100px; float: left;">Label 2</label> Bar
</p>
```

You could also discard the float property and use display: inline-block instead, but watch out for IE6.

Comment: What about fluid width labels in CSS? Imagine that the label text is database driven. It would be ideal if the label had no line wrapping and "Foo" is still vertically aligned with "Bar".

Comment: That's much more difficult, since the labels aren't aware of each others widths.  You could create a two-column layout to achieve this, but then you run into the possibility of vertical alignment issues. It's probably best to stick to a convention to ensure the text remains under a certain length, then you can enforce it by using a fixed width along with overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;  Unfortunately, this remains a somewhat difficult task without the use of a table.

Comment: S.N. LaViska: IMO, this is example of when it's okay to use tables for layout instead of CSS. When the CSS becomes horribly convoluted and hacky, you have to ask yourself if it's really more elegant than simply using a table.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width: 30%;">
   <div style="float: right;">
      <div>
          foo 
      </div>
      <div>
          bar
      </div>
   </div>

   <div style="float: left;">
      <div> 
         <label>label1</label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>label2</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can view the output here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7XZx/

Comment: it should look like a table if foo or bar are long praragraphs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/59GqN/.
[image: Foobar is foobar]

It's complete overkill, but it seems to work. (I'd use tables if it takes me more than 20 minutes to figure out how to make it work without them. I do *not* promote them for site layout, though, but lay off the hate on the tables).

Good luck!